# Cannot establish ssl connection to own microservice with a wildcard certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, wildcard

I wrote a microservice with spring boot which uses my own wildcard certificate (from a public CA). If a consumer calls my microservice (regardless of technology), an error is thrown.

My wildcard certificate is also used to host our company website. If a consumer opens an SSL connection to our company website, everything is fine, no error is thrown.
I tried to play with some trustore stuff, but really, I don't want to do it. I could add the (intermediate) certificate to my local truststore, but everybody who wants to use my microservice, would have to do it.

There must be an other, easier way.
Is my microservice supposed to send the full certification path in the response, including the intermediate certificate? And if yes, how can I manage to do this with spring boot?

To open a https connection, I use the following snippet.

```
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.getInputStream();
//output inputstream
```

Of couse, if I initialize an SSL context with an empty trustmanager and set the hostname verifying to `false` it works. But that's insane.

The error I get is if open a 'clean' connection

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Your Java truststore does not seem to have the CA the certificate uses, hence it can't validate it.

Comment: I agree with Patrick.  The truststore of the client you're using doesn't seem to have the public CA in it.  You can print out the list of CAs that your truststore is using with the following command `keytool -v -list -keystore <keystore_location>`.  This will show you all the certificates that your client currently trusts.  You can then take the fingerprint of the wildcard certificate and see if it is in the list of trusted CAs in your truststore.  Here is a reasonable write up of the same steps:  https://medium.com/@codebyamir/the-java-developers-guide-to-ssl-certificates-b78142b3a0fc

Comment: @PatrickMevzek and hooknc thanks for your answers. I see where you're coming from. But what I then don't understand is, why I am able to open an SSL connection to my website (www.xxx.com) with no error but get the above mentioned error when connecting to (yyy.xxx.com)? Both servers use the same wildcard certificate.

Comment: "Both servers use the same wildcard certificate. "  your computer seems to disagree with you because if both connections used the exact same certificate you would have get the same error twice.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek ok, fixed the issue. I created a new PKCS12 File including the intermediate certificates. (`openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privateKey.key -in cert.cabundle.all -out bundleAllIn.p12 -name tomcat`). Now everything works. The website is using the dedicated privateKey, wildcart certificate and ca-cert bundle. My former PKCS12 didn't include the ca-cert bundle - that's why it didn't work in the first place. Thanks for your help, guys!